# Run script in background to send files through ftp

Tags: bash, shell-script, ftp, vsftpd

I've made a script that automatically sends a file to another machine via ftp. Only thing you need to do is to input the IP, file name, user and password.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Server ip " server
read -p "File you want to transfer " file
read -p "Name of the user " user
read -p "Password " password

ftp -inv $server <<END_SCRIPT
user $user $password
cd /home
put /home/student/$file
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

However, what I want to achieve is to send this file every hour once you've run the script to input the necessary data, while being able to use the terminal without having to open a new one.

Any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is using `scp` or `sftp` an option? Because if you're using plain FTP then you're hosed securitywise right out of the starting gate.

Comment: I'm using plain ftp but I'll later encrypt the password. It's enough to fulfill my needs.